# Prove the theorem complete metric space associated with equivalent norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be vector space over field $F$. Two norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ on $X$ is equivalent if there exist $k,K\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
k\Vert x\Vert_1\leq \Vert x\Vert_2\leq K\Vert x\Vert_1
$$
or 
$$
K^{-1}\Vert x\Vert_2\leq \Vert x\Vert_1\leq k^{-1}\Vert x\Vert_2
$$ for all $x\in X$.

Now, I want to prove this theorem.

Let $X$ be vector space over field $F$. If $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ is equivalent on $X$ with metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively, then
"metric space $(X,d_1)$ is complete if and only if metric space $(X,d_2)$ is complete".

A metric space $(X, d)$ is said to be complete if every Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges (to a point in $X$).

A sequence in metric space $(X,d)$ is called Cauchy sequence if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $m,n>N$, $d(x_m,x_n)<\varepsilon$.

I don't understand how to proof this theorem. I don't know how to associate between definition of complete metric space and equivalent norm. Any idea how to proof this theorem?

Comment: How about using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350457/proof-the-theorem-of-two-normed-space-are-equivalent?rq=1) theorem?

Comment: The associated metrics are $d_k (x,y)=\| x-y\|_k $. They have the same convergent sequences and the same Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Thank you very much!